# Why WidgetsBinding is called multiple times when resizing browser window

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter and came across this issue that I do not understand.

When running simple widget code on the browser for testing, the print function is called, No problem so far. when resizing the browser window just normal way by mouse then the print function is called so many times.

how to prevent this behaviour and limit calling print function only when the wedget is loaded the first time or if came back to it from another widget.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  print("WidgetsBinding");
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is called after each `build` method.
Whenever the browser's size changes the `build` method is called so your app can adapt to the new size.